# Find $\alpha^{2016} + \beta^{2016} + \alpha^{2014} + \beta^{2014} \over \alpha^{2015} + \beta^{2015}$ for zeroes of the polynomial $x^2+3x +1$

Tags: polynomials, roots

We have a polynomial $x^2 + 3x + 1$. There are 2 zeroes of it,

$\alpha$ and $\beta$

Now, what we need to find out is(What I couldn't) is as follows:

$$ \alpha^{2016} + \beta^{2016} + \alpha^{2014} + \beta^{2014} \over \alpha^{2015} + \beta^{2015}$$

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks a lot!
-bone

Comment: Are you sure that the polynomial is not $x^2+3x+1$?

Comment: im unsure. i remember this question was told to me in school and no one in the class could solve it. but, maybe it is x^2+3x+1.. can you tell me how to solve it like that?

Comment: If $x^2+3x+1=0$ has a root $\alpha,$ then $\alpha^2+1=-3\alpha$

In the numerator, $\alpha^{2016}+\alpha^{2014}=\alpha^{2014}(\alpha^2+1)=\cdots$

Comment: but what about beta?

Comment: Replace $\alpha$ with $\beta$

Comment: ill edit the main question. can you post a complete answer? much appreciated

Comment: Awww - it would have been more interesting with the original minus sign :-)

Comment: how can you do it with minus? @JyrkiLahtonen can you do it please?

Comment: It would be a complicated rational number close to $-\sqrt{13}$. I certainly don't want to calculate it by hand :-)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932358/find-the-value-of-frac-alpha2014-beta2014-alpha2016-beta2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x^2+3x+1=0$ has a root $\alpha,$ then $\alpha^2+1=-3\alpha$

In the numerator, $\displaystyle \alpha^{2016}+\alpha^{2014}=\alpha^{2014}(\alpha^2+1)=\alpha^{2014}(-3\alpha)=-3\alpha^{2015}$

Similarly, $\beta$ is another root of $x^2+3x+1=0, $

$\displaystyle\beta^{2016}+\beta^{2014}=\cdots=-3\beta^{2015}$

So, the numerator becomes $\cdots$

Comment: that wont finish the answer.. we cant cut the values from the denominator and the top since they are being added.. can you please complete it? :3

Comment: @Bone, So, the numerator becomes $$-3(\alpha^{2015}+\beta^{2015})$$

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhh.. cool awesome man.. <3

gotcha.. thanks a lot

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  once again I must quote Bob Marley:  ***nice one!!!*** That be some kinky reggae, mon'! +1!

Answer (score 0):

By general theory on recurrence equations, the sequence $(\alpha^n+\beta^n)$ is the unique solution of the recurrence equation
$$
a_{n+2}=-3a_{n+1}-a_n,\qquad a_0=2,\quad a_1=-3
$$
In particular,
$$
a_{n+2}+a_{n}=-3a_{n+1}
$$
so
$$
\frac{a_{n+2}+a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=-3
$$