# Find the value of $\frac{\alpha^{2014}+\beta^{2014}+\alpha^{2016}+\beta^{2016}}{\alpha^{2015}+\beta^{2015}}$ for the roots of $x^2-3x+1$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I got this problem from my textbook, not school. I tried various methods but was unable to solve the problem.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of the polynomial $x^2-3x+1$. I need to find the value of
$$ \frac{\alpha^{2014}+\beta^{2014}+\alpha^{2016}+\beta^{2016}}{\alpha^{2015}+\beta^{2015}}$$

Comment: Note that $\alpha^{2014}+\alpha^{2016}=\alpha^{2014}(\alpha^2+1)$ and also that $\alpha^2+1=3\alpha$ (and the same with $\beta$).

Comment: Problems like this always yield to [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).  You have $\alpha+ \beta=3, \alpha \beta=1$  Have you tried to use that?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789901/find-alpha2016-beta2016-alpha2014-beta2014-over-alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to realize that $\alpha^2 + 1 = 3 \alpha$, and $\beta^2 + 1 = 3\beta$.

Using this, we have $\alpha^{2016} + \alpha^{2014}= \alpha^{2014}(3\alpha) = 3\alpha^{2015}$

Combining this with the analogous expression in $\beta$, we can write

$$\frac{\alpha^{2016} + \beta^{2016} + \alpha^{2014} + \beta^{2014}}{\alpha^{2015} + \beta^{2015}} = \frac{3(\alpha^{2015} +\beta^{2015})}{(\alpha^{2015} +\beta^{2015})} = 3$$

Comment: Wow the solution was so simple

Comment: @superbjhon I don't think it would have been obvious to me when learning it. Paying attention to the relationships between roots was not something I would not have thought to do until someone pointed it out to me in undergraduate modern algebra.

Comment: Good.  Which university ar u from